# Why does minwindowheight not work in xaml for adaptive designing

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I am making a windows universal app using XAML and C#. I want to use visual state triggers and my code below makes changes to the body background based on the screen width of the device the app is running on.

```
 <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

        <VisualStateGroup>

            <VisualState x:Name="Phone">

                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth = "0"/>
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>

                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target = "Body.Background"
                 Value = "#21539E" />
                </VisualState.Setters>

            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="Tablets">

                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth = "720" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>

                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target = "Body.Background"
                 Value = "Red" />
                </VisualState.Setters>

            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="Laptop">

                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth = "1024" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>

                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target = "Body.Background"
                 Value = "Black" />
                </VisualState.Setters>

            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="PCs">

                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth = "1400" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>

                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target = "Body.Background"
                 Value = "Green" />
                </VisualState.Setters>

            </VisualState>

        </VisualStateGroup>

    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

But when I do the same thing for the minimunwindow height property it does not work.

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

        <VisualStateGroup>

            <VisualState x:Name="Phone">

                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowHeight = "0"/>
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>

                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target = "Body.Background"
                 Value = "#21539E" />
                </VisualState.Setters>

            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="Tablets">

                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowHeight = "120" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>

                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target = "Body.Background"
                 Value = "Red" />
                </VisualState.Setters>

            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="Laptop">

                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowHeight = "1024" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>

                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target = "Body.Background"
                 Value = "Black" />
                </VisualState.Setters>

            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="PCs">

                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowHeight = "1400" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>

                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target = "Body.Background"
                 Value = "Green" />
                </VisualState.Setters>

            </VisualState>

        </VisualStateGroup>

    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I implement minimum window height correctly?

Comment: Your code looks quite reasonable. What screen resolution are you testing this on? Also, not sure if the `MinWindowHeight` using 'effective pixels' is making a difference?

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me, the only problem is that you probably don't see any change same as me.

It's because the sizes of MinWindowHeight are in ['effective pixels'](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff684173(v=vs.85).aspx), not in your monitor's pixels, so you aren't able to stretch your windows as much as AdaptiveTrigger could be fired.

Try to change your MinWindowHeight size's to 400, 500, 600, 700 and you'll see it.